# Why My Static Routing Commands Don't Work?

Tags: networking, routes, router, cisco

I want to try routing on routers. Router does not show me my static routing commands.
[image]

I used this static routing command on Router0
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 1.1.1.2

I used this static routing command on Router1
ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 1.1.1.1

Router0

```
Router#
Router#conf ter
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 1.1.1.2
Router(config)#end
Router#
%SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console

Router#show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
       i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
       * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
       P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     1.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C       1.1.1.0/24 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
L       1.1.1.1/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
     192.168.1.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C       192.168.1.0/24 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1
L       192.168.1.3/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1

Router#
```

Router1

```
Router>en
Router#conf ter
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 1.1.1.1
Router(config)#end
Router#
%SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console

Router#show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
       i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
       * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
       P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     1.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C       1.1.1.0/24 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
L       1.1.1.2/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
     192.168.2.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C       192.168.2.0/24 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1
L       192.168.2.3/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1

Router#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 is the same route as 192.168.1.0/24, and 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 is the same route as 192.168.2.0/24.  Since these routes are already in the routing tables as "connected" which has a lower **administrative distance** (= 0) than "static" (= 1), the static route is not installed in the routing tables. (commingling this notation was a bad design decision by crisco imo)

Comment: the "show running-configuration" command should show these 2 configured routes btw

Comment: @shiva13  if that answer solved your issue, please accept it  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because the next hop is unreachable.  Can you ping 1.1.1.2|1 from Router0|1?  Post the show ip route outputs.  Also, ensure you are in config mode.  (maybe you need to commit too as on a Juniper, if cisco has added that needed concept yet)

Comment: i can ping 1.1.1.2 from router0 and i can ping 1.1.1.1 from router1

Comment: it does not shows my routing commands. i wrote them on configure terminal